# Client Authentification with jersey

Tags: java, authentication, jersey

I'm trying to establish a https connection: a client side authentification! I use jersey on my client. The client certificate is in my resource folder.
How can I approach this in java code?

The server is a tomcat server. What do I have to configure on the server side to get this work. I am fairly new to this topic so please can you help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder` class provides the following methods to configure a client-side certificate.

- `keyStore(KeyStore, char[])`
- `keyStore(KeyStore, String)`
- `sslContext(SSLContext)`
- `trustStore(KeyStore)`